# A program for quick and easy typesetting of formulas in latex

Tags: mathtools, tools

Is there an additional toolbox for a simpler set of formulas in latex?  After all, it is difficult and not visual to type this using symbols.  Also interested in the same for creating tables.  It seems that I have heard about this somewhere

Comment: Check out [Lyx](https://www.lyx.org/) , it has the option to use LaTeX or click on formulas like you might do in word document

Comment: after a while, most people find that it is much faster to type the latex directly than to use some visual palette system to enter mathematics or tables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found the use of a mouse to enter equations to be the most abominable system imaginable.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes what is a mouse?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, if you can imagine a widget attached to your RS-232 interface, driven by your Motorola 6502 processor, using a software driver loaded from your 5 1/4" floppy drive...it's something like that.  Best of all, the driver only uses 4096 bytes of RAM!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't forget, I work about 100 yards from where the ENIAC sat.  Here was its first program: https://computerhistory.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/programing-the-eniac-VonNeumannFlowchart.png